# Don't know how to use Geofire for android

Tags: android, geofire

Can someone please make a video on getting started with Geofire for Android, please! I've already seen some videos online but they aren't very good

Comment: you will get very good tutorial playlist in youtube from user "simcoder". follow this playlist for your Geofire https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3HdOTQ8YHI&list=PLxabZQCAe5fgXx8cn2iKOtt0VFJrf5bOd

Comment: @SAM  Thanks for the link, working out great so far

Comment: Happy Coding bro...